# Most efficient way of selecting thousands of rows from a list of ids

Tags: mysql

Are there any scalable ways of selecting thousands of rows using mysql IN or something similar?

E.g.

```
SELECT * FROM awesomeTable WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4......100000)
```

Is this possible or am I just dreaming? Schema is InnoDB, can be changed if another would provide a more scalable solution.

For reference I am getting search results from a set of ids returned from Solr. I'd like to use mysql for the final retrieval as it would make sorting and final filtering of these results much easier (I won't get into the details of why).

**EDIT:**

The query could be use a LIMIT clause as long as the IN still contained all 100000 of the ids

E.g.

```
SELECT * FROM awesomeTable WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4......100000) LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: its better to use solr's sorting if you want to achieve performance.

Comment: Do you really have to fetch the actual content of all thousand rows? Can't you do your pagination algo and then start fetching per page?

Comment: @cherouvim he needs to do sorting.thats why he is selecting all the records i assume.

Comment: @sathis Exactly. Sorting in this case is based off another table. Consolidating all of this into solr isn't something I'd like to tackle right now as it could take considerable time

Comment: Not sure it can really be any more efficient. Think about it. You have to transfer all the IDS to mysql (a simple comma seperated list is pretty compact), and mysql has to process the list. Maybe Prepared Statements would help (proper, not software emulated) as the ids could be sent as a binary list - saving mysql a bit of text parsing) - but at the end of the day still reckon you doing it wrong. If you can't do final sorting and filtering on solr, change to something else!

Comment: @barryhunter This was my thinking as well, but I just wanted to be sure. Unfortunately I only really need solr for certain search cases which I suspect won't come up very often, and the needed changes to make it work properly with solr will take a non-negligible amount of time to implement.

Comment: Do you really need to fetch all of 100000 records (not using `LIMIT`)?

Comment: @galymzhan I don't necessarily need to fetch all of the records, but the IN would need to contain all 10000 of the records for sorting purposes.

Answer (score 1):

I that were me, and not really knowing your framework, you should try inserting those ID into a temporary table and using this table with a simple inner join. That could prove to be as fast as this IN.

Comment: I was thinking about this, but wouldn't the write overhead when calling INSERT for potentially hundreds of thousands of ids outweigh any benefits gained from the inner join?

Comment: Even more importantly, there's usually an upper limit to how big (in characters) a single SQL query can get. A long `IN()` list is a good way to hit that limit. Using a temp table avoids this. Also, the temp table solution can be much more efficient if you need to use the list more than once.

Comment: Which would be probably the case if it's a search, since you might want to paginate the result.

Comment: I tried it on a relatively big table and while IN takes about one minute to complete, INNER JOIN finishes in less than 100 ms.

Answer (score 0):

I came up to the same question while inserting into mysql tables.
The possible query size depends on your mysql configuration.

My approach was to split the big ids collection into some parts.

Using Ruby on Rails:

```
all_ids.each_slice(10000) do |ids_part|
  query = "INSERT INTO ..."
end
```

Perhaps this could also be a solution for selecting rows by ids.