# Select thousands of rows by IDs in Rails ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm trying to select thousands of rows from a list of IDs in Rails. Basically is there a good way to answer this problem in rails:
[Most efficient way of selecting thousands of rows from a list of ids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8022003/most-efficient-way-of-selecting-thousands-of-rows-from-a-list-of-ids)

Something like:

```
big_array = [1,3,53,68,...,100003,100040]
users = User.find(big_array)
```

I thought about using 
[rails mass import](https://github.com/arunagw/activerecord-extensions) and then doing a join on the imported data. However, I would prefer not to re-engineer this, if it already exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`each_slice` (pure ruby) will probably perform better than `in_groups_of` (rails method that uses `each_slice` internally by the way)

```
big_array.each_slice(1000) do |ids|
  users = User.find(ids)
  ...
end
```

Where do you get that `big_array` from?
There is maybe a more idiomatic solution with [`find_each` or `find_in_batches`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html)

Comment: big array is coming out of R via RSRuby

Answer (score 0):

If the ids are sorted, group them and query in pieces (if they are not sorted, sort them):

```
lots_of_ids.in_groups_of( 100, false ) do |ids|
    models = MyModel.find( ids )
    models.do_whatever_you_want_with_them
end
```

Comment: Whoops, forgot the **false** parameter to tell rails not to fill in the groups with nil.